# How to stop Recyclerview from producing duplicates and stop shuffling items?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am a newbie here and iam developing a notes app. I noticed that my notes in recyclerview are getting duplicated and shuffling positions upon scrolling. I have spend hurs changing and modifying the code but with no luck . Hope you guys go through the code .Thankyou for your time.

**The relevant adapter code is **

```
                public void setdata(List<NotesEntry> notesEntries) {
                    notesEntryList=notesEntries;  //i used your code here .it gives a null pointer exception
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                public List<NotesEntry> getnotesentries() {
                    return notesEntryList;
                }

                @Override
                public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
                    try {

                        int i = v1.getAdapterPosition();
                        NotesEntry notesEntries = notesEntryList.get(position);
                        id = notesEntries.getId();
                        text = notesEntries.getText();
                        Log.d("idies", text);
                        b1.setText(String.valueOf(id));
                        textview1.setText(text);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }



                public interface Itemlistener {
                    void clicked(int clickedposition, View v, int id, String text);

                }

                class Viewholder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
                    public Viewholder1(@NonNull View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        textview1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                        b1 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

                        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
                        textview1.setOnClickListener(this);

                        Log.d("ViewHolder1", "h");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        itemlistener.clicked(getAdapterPosition(), view, notesEntryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), notesEntryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getText());

                    }
                }

            }
```

**This is how i have implemented my onclick method in main activity**

```
@Override
public void clicked(int clickedposition, View v, int iditem, String textitem) {
    try {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2:
                entries = adapter.getnotesentries();// entries of notes in my list
                int n = db.Dao().delete(entries.get(clickedposition));
                retrievetasks();

                break;
            case R.id.textView2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notes.class);
                intent.putExtra("newnotes", defaultnotes);
                intent.putExtra("id", iditem);
                intent.putExtra("text", textitem);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

    } catch (Exception E) {
        E.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}`

I will provide extra code if needed.

Comment: Are you duplicating data with this line adapter.setdata(db.Dao().loadalltasks()); ?

What if you call adapter.clear() before setting data?

Comment: I am using the above method you mentioned to set set the adapter for refreshing data after deleting tasks. Am not sure what is causing the duplications. Even if i dont delete any task ,the data still gets duplicated on scrolling.@JAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer finally ,the solution to stop recycler view from duplicating data is by removing the views from your layout before setting data to adapter each time.This worked for me .
example:

```
layoutManager.removeAllViews()
```

And never forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged` after retrieving data to adapter .
Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the item from the DB, you should either :

- Reload the whole list and reset the adapter (changing the list 
  and `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `setData()`).
- Remove the item from the **adapter's** list, then call `notifyItemRemoved()`

Doing both confuses the adapter, because it thinks that you are removing items from the list you have just set (which does not contains the removed item)

Comment: I did as you mentioned in your first point ,as it did not work i used notifyitemremoved method .Also it is shuffling data while scrolling even without any deletions.    @bwt

Comment: i.e. without having used the code in `clicked` or  `itemremovednotifier` ?

Comment: it seems that there is a `try` clause, are exception and shuffling correlated ?

Comment: i removed notifyDataSetChanged() method .Even now it doesn't work and also the adapter data does not get reflected in Ui unless i restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

To stop duplicate your RecyclerView items make sure to clear your List model then fetch your list model:

```
List<myModel> myData = new ArrayList<>();

myData.clear();
```